# Can we use 'Firestore' like this?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I downloaded flutter chat app on [Github](https://github.com/sharansingh00002/flutter_chat) and I was learning through it. The original developer used Firestore but in mine, I am getting an error "Undefined name 'Firestore'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name" like this.

I search for this and I read in [cloudfirestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) docs we can use "FirebaseFirestore" (maybe I am wrong). I am learning to write backend with flutter and so far I did UI parts. so this is my first attempt at learning backend with flutter.

```
handleSignIn() async {
    final res = await googleSignIn.signIn();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final auth = await res.authentication;

    final credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: auth.idToken, accessToken: auth.accessToken);

    final firebaseUser =
        (await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credentials)).user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      final result = (await Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .where('id', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
              .getDocuments())
          .documents;

      if (result.length == 0) {
        ///new user
        Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(firebaseUser.uid)
            .setData({
          "id": firebaseUser.uid,
          "name": firebaseUser.displayName,
          "profile_pic": firebaseUser.photoURL,
          "created_at": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        });

        sharedPreferences.setString("id", firebaseUser.uid);
        sharedPreferences.setString("name", firebaseUser.displayName);
        sharedPreferences.setString("profile_pic", firebaseUser.photoURL);

        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
      } else {
        ///Old user
        sharedPreferences.setString("id", result[0]["id"]);
        sharedPreferences.setString("name", result[0]["name"]);
        sharedPreferences.setString("profile_pic", result[0]["profile_pic"]);

        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
      }
    }
  }
```

this is the error I'm getting
[image]

so can you guys explain how to solve this error?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are missing to add [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/example) dependency in pubspec.yml. One more thing,

you are using latest version, use "FirebaseFirestore" instead of "Firestore".

Answer (score 1):

- Go to `pubspec.yaml` file in your flutter project.
  Add this( `cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0` ) below dependencies like in the image below.
- You can skip this step if you use VScode. It does this automatically if you save the file after the update.
  **IF NOT** , do `flutter pub get` inside your project. (this fetches the new packages added to the project, in our case `cloud_firestore`)
- Make sure that you are able to see this import in the file you are getting the errors in.

> import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

- Next, update **`Firestore.instance`** -> **`FirebaseFirestore.instance`** in all your files where you are getting this error.

[image]

Comment: ok thank you.  when I use firebasefirestore that problem solved. but ".document(firebaseUser.uid)" line has new error "The method 'document' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'."

Answer (score 1):

Use this code --

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users").add({"name": "Majeed"});
```

change Firestore with FirebaseFirestore and remove the Document and setData
replace setData with add.